# Magic Mock being used when not specifically asked for

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I have 3 classes, say FirstObject, ObjectCreatorHelper and SecondObject.

ObjectCreatorHelper has a static method `CreateObject`, which creates an object of type FirstObject.

SecondObject's ctor takes a parameter, which is of type FirstObject. It also has a method called `run`

In another file, where I am using an object of class SecondObject, I am calling the `run` method parallely, like so:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
    pool.starmap(second_object.run_model, zip(["Hello"], [1]))
```

In the unit test, I am using

```
mock.patch(module.ObjectCreatorHelper.CreateObject) as create_object_mock:
    create_object_mock.return_value = MagicMock()
```

I can see that CreateObject is never called, meaning I am getting a mock of FirstObject. This is then used when SecondObject is instantiated.

When the test runs, I get an error:
`An exception of type PicklingError occurred. Can't pickle class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock': it's not the same object as unittest.mock.MagicMock`

This error occurs in the multiprocessing code snippet I pasted above.

I don't understand why second_object is being considered as MagicMock. Only FirstObject is a mock.

Also, is there any way to fix this?